# Node.JS nodePDF

Tags: node.js, pdf

I have this NODE server. And I use the nodePDF module to make pdf files based on a URL.

the module:   https://github.com/TJkrusinski/NodePDF

Making the file works perfect. However it always shows up in my root. I would like to change to path where the file ends up to /public/bills but I have no idea how to do this. I tried googling it but couldn't find a decent answer.

MY CODE:

```
router.get('/summonPhantom', function (req, res, next) {
var NodePDF = require('nodepdf');

var pdf = new NodePDF('http://www.google.com',req.session.ticket+'_factuur.pdf', {
    'viewportSize': {
        'width': 1440,
        'height': 900
    },
    'args': '--debug=true'
});

pdf.on('error', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});

pdf.on('done', function (pathToFile) {
    console.log("done");
    console.log(pathToFile);
});


pdf.on('stdout', function (stdout) {
    // handle
});


pdf.on('stderr', function (stderr) {
    // handle
});


res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
var json = JSON.stringify({
    bericht: "MAGIC IS NOT FOR EVERYONE, PLEASE CONSULT A WIZARD BEFORE USE.",
});
res.end(json);

});
```

As you can see the .on has a pathToFile, but how do I overwrite it?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the filename (path) as the second parameter

`NodePDF(url, fileName, opts...`

So change your code as follows:

```
var pdf = new NodePDF('http://www.google.com',req.session.ticket+'_factuur.pdf', 'directory/filename.pdf', {
    'viewportSize': {
        'width': 1440,
        'height': 900
    },
    'args': '--debug=true'
});
```

Comment: do you have the rights or does the folder exists? try adding a slash at the beginning '/directory/filename.pdf'

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the help. But I made a seperate PHP invoice server. which works with html2pdf. I wil try this weekend to see if a I still can find a solution. For the sake of futur readers.